# H field in reflection of EM waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I was reading "principles of electomagnetics by sadiku" and there is a diagram concerning reflection of EM waves [image: As given in sadiku]

But images on the net [image] are different . In the first image the H-field is going into the page in the reflected ray but in the second image they are all coming out of the page . Which is correct?

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218478/plane-wave-normal-incidence-on-dielectric-direction-of-fields/218516#218516

Answer (score 1):

Flipping the direction of the vector and changing the sign of its amplitude leaves the vector the same (Essentially, $a \hat x = -a (-\hat x)$).

If you notice, the direction of electric field is flipped too. Both conventions are correct, and the reflection coefficient gets an additional negative sign when comparing the conventions.